# GWT 1.6.4 on FreeBSD?

Tags: java, maven-2, gwt, freebsd

Anyone have GWT 1.6.4 running on FreeBSD?  Our build server is a FreeBSD box, and dies with the following when we try to compile:

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000800d0c724, pid=4749[thread 34370233088 also had an error], tid=0xa02d80

#
# Java VM: Diablo Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x20c724]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/home/username/reporting/hs_err_pid4749.log
#
# Please submit bug reports to freebsd-java@FreeBSD.org
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Interestingly, Maven seems to include `gwt-dev-1.6.4-linux.jar` in the classpath, presumably because there is no version for FreeBSD; I don't know if this is related or not.  We are just trying to compile, not use hosted mode, so I don't believe any native libraries are actually required.  This used to work fine for us with GWT 1.5.

Comment: Looks like you posted twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853958/gwt-1-6-4-on-freebsd

Comment: Please delete the other (duplicate) question. Thanks!

Comment: I fat-fingered the keyboard and double-posted, oops!  I deleted the old one, thanks.

Comment: If comments can be deleted, can these four (including mine) be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We seem to have dodged this by using JDK5 to compile our GWT-based code.  Not a perfect solution, but a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

If you search Google for that frame (libjvm.so+0x20c724) you find some [relevant](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-java/2009-March/008016.html) recent [threads](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-java/2009-April/008047.html) on the freebsd-java list.

Looks like the problem might be related to IPv6?  The solution proposed there was to add
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
to the configuration.

It's unusual to see a FreeBSD build system for java; there isn't a lot of flexibility or support for Java on that platform.  Is your product deployed on FreeBSD as well?  If the solution above doesn't work, you may have to get more closely engaged with the freebsd-java community or else consider trying another platform for the build.

Comment: Due to historical and security reasons, our product is built on FreeBSD.  The Java part of it is only a small piece.  If I had my druthers, I'd do exactly as you recommend and move to something a little better supported such as Linux.